# Visual Studio: is it possible to add a reference to a project which does not contain a main and not get errors?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I've been working some with visual studio and I've been constantly frustrated by the fact that whenever I've added a reference to another project it has created errors because that other project does not contain a main. It shouldn't contain a main. It is set to be a class library, so I am unsure why it thinks there should be a main there. Can anyone help?

Comment: Make sure you select your start-up project and choose "Set as startup project"

Comment: I have set my start up project to be the project which has a main (the one which is making a reference to my class library)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured out what was wrong and I'm going to record it here so hopefully someone else stumbling into this can benefit from it. If you change the type of your project so that it will be a class library AFTER you've added the reference that reference will not update. You will need to remove it then add it again. Then you will need to make sure you've built your class library so that it will generate the DLLs. 
This is probably Visual Studio 101 but I've been fighting with this problem for weeks now and I've looked around quite a few times and never seen this explained anywhere.